# Anonymous users can connect to MongoDB with security.authorization enabled

Tags: mongodb

I have enabled the `security.authorization` setting in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

But I am still able to connect to the mongo shell without providing credentials.

```
mongo
```

Enabling `security.authorization` seems to enforce access control on the databases and the anonymous user doesn't seem to be able to perform any actions such as listing databases and/or collections.

I have attempted to enable auth in the `/etc/mongodb.conf` file, but this didn't seem to have any effect and I can still connect anonymously.

```
auth = true
```

How do I set the mongo shell to require authentication so that anonymous connections are blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization mode in mongodb does not work like mysql.
It will prevent non authorized or anonymous users to read or write the DB but it won't forbid people to connect to your DB.

Anonymous users will always be able to connect themselves but can't do anything.

If you want to block the connection from unknown users or server, you can enable the [net.bindIp parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) to allow only the selected IP to connect to your database.

Comment: bindIp is already set to localhost, I'm surprised there's no way to prevent anonymouse connections.

Comment: @Sinfieldd if bindIp  is set your DB is totally safe. Yes, I find mongodb authorizations pretty bad compared to simple system like mysql. I guess they wanted to do better but...

Comment: I was considering switching to Neo4j for my project anyway, thanks for the help here